# Powershell curl to an URL throws WebCmdletWebResponseException

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl

I'm trying to access/download a file from our URL, this URL basically downloads a file from s3 bucket(reverse proxy via nginx). Using **AWS ACM for SSL certificates**.

When I'm trying to download the file using that URL on the Windows16 instance it is throwing **WebCmdletWebResponseException**. Below is the detailed error message.

```
   curl : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
   At line:1 char:1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**Findings:**

- The same URL works fine with windows 19 and 22 editions.
- Through other blogs and posts found that the issue is because Powershell by default uses TLS 1.0 to connect to the website, but website security requires TLS 1.2.

But if I try to use the s3 URL directly to download the file it is working fine. Both the s3 URL and our URL certificate have TLS 1.2.

Can someone please help to solve this issue?